# Can a Linux-process intercept signals sent to its child?

Tags: linux, shell-script, process, signals, process-management

I have a shell-wrapper around a large executable. It does something like this:

```
run/the/real/executable "$@" &
PID=$!
# perform
# a few
# minor things
wait $PID
# perform some
# post-processing
```

One of the things it does after the `wait` is check for core-dumps and handle process the crashes, however, by then the process is already dead and some information no longer available.

Can the fatal signal (`SIGSEGV` or `SIGBUS`) be intercepted by the shell script before it is delivered to the child itself?

I'd then be able to, for example, perform `lsof -p $PID` to get the list of files opened by the wrapped process before it dies...

*Update*: I tried using `strace` to catch the process receiving a signal. Unfortunately, there seems to be a race -- when `strace` reports the child's signal, the child is on its way out and there is no telling, whether the `lsof` will get the list of its files or not...

Here is the test script, which spawns off `/bin/sleep` and tries to get the files it has opened for writing. Some times the `/tmp/sleep-output.txt` is reported as it should be, other times the list is empty...

```
ulimit -c 0
/bin/sleep 15 > /tmp/sleep-output.txt &

NPID=$!

echo "Me: $$, sleep: $NPID"

(sleep 3; kill -BUS $NPID) &

ps -ww $NPID
while read line
do
        set -x
        outputfiles=$(lsof -F an -b -w -p $NPID | sed -n '/^aw$/ {n; s,.,,; p}')
        ps -ww $NPID
        lsof -F an -b -w -p $NPID
        break
done < <(strace -qq -p $NPID -e trace=signal 2>&1)
echo $outputfiles

wait $NPID
```

The above test requires use of `ksh` or `bash` (for the `< <(...)` construct to work).

Comment: The shell can't do this, you need to write a program that uses `ptrace`.

Comment: Shell can spawn off `strace`... Or some other equivalent of attaching debugger. But doing that will prevent usage of `lsof` -- which seems to also use ptrace-interface.

Comment: `strace` will just report that the process received the signal, it won't stop it so you can examine the process at that moment.

Comment: If I run `strace -qq -e trace=signal -p $PID | read line`, my script can wait until the process gets a signal. Trouble is, when that happens, it is already too late. With whatever I code using `ptrace`, it may be the same problem -- can't run `lsof`, while ptrace is in effect, but, as soon as the `ptrace` is lifted, the child will exit...

Comment: When you use `ptrace`, the process stops when the tracing process is notified of a signal. The tracing process has to tell it to resume. `strace` does that after it prints the message, but if you write your own program you can keep it stopped until after you run `lsof`.

Comment: I had the impression, `lsof` tries to ptrace the process too, which would fail if my program is ptrace-ing it already...

Comment: I can't think of any reason why `lsof` would need to use `ptrace`. I think it just looks in `/proc`

Comment: You are right, `lsof` does not use `ptrace`. Unfortunately, it is still not a reliable method -- see my update to the question. How would my hypothetical program use ptrace(2) differently from how strace(1) uses it?

Comment: When a process being traced receives a signal, it stops. The tracing process uses `wait()` or `waitpid()` to wait for this to happen. It can then run `lsof`, or do the equivalent by listing `/proc/<pid>/fd`. Once it's done it calls `ptrace()` with the `PTRACE_CONT` request to let the process continue.

Comment: Ok, so you think, `strace` lets the process continue (to its death), whereas my custom program will do the file-listing first thus avoiding the race... Ok, I'll try. Do you expect the traced process to run any slower because of the tracing, though?

Comment: Yes, `strace` simply prints the reason the process stopped and then tells it to continue immediately. Your program can do something else. I'm not sure of the exact impact on the process being trace, I'd expect it only to be slowed down when something happens that stops it, since the tracer has to tell it to resume.

Comment: Thanks. Why don't you shape your comments into an answer, which I'll be able to "accept"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no shell methods to do what you're trying, it will have to be done from a custom program.

Use [`ptrace()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) to monitor the process, similar to the way a debugger does. When the process receives a signal, it will be stopped, and the monitoring program will be notified (its call to `wait()` will return, and `WIFSTOPPED(status)` will be true).

It can then run `lsof -p <pid>` to list the open files of the process, and then call `ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, NULL, 0)` to restart the process.

Comment: Thanks. Wish, I could just [get the list of opened files from the process' core-dump instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451352/)...