# Make usual programs use the alternate screen

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, top

This has been annoying me for ages. Even though I use a modern terminal emulator and most CLI programs, such as `less` and `vim`, are able to use the alternate screen adequately (*i.e.* entering it on startup and leaving it on exit), some are reluctant to do so. Rogue programs include `top`, `screen` and [`dialog`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510752/bash-utility-dialog-leaves-a-messy-screen).

When they start, these programs clear the contents of the window (*i.e.* the last N lines where N is the height of the terminal window). When they exit, some (`top`) leave their last state visible, while others (`screen`) clear the screen again. In all cases, the last N lines of scrollback buffer have been overwritten.

I checked this on various machines over time, and in various terminal emulators, including `xcfce4-terminal`, `urxvt` and `screen` (the alternate screen of which being properly enabled, using `:altscreen on`). Hence I do not think it is a problem with my terminal, I rather believe it is the built-in behavior of these programs (at least unpatched, as they are distributed in Archlinux).

**So my questions are:**

1. Why do these programs behave like this? I guess there are good reasons for it?
2. How can I work around it? Currently, I am using dumb wrapper scripts like the one below, but maybe there is a cleaner way?

   ```
   # save this as: ~/bin/top

   if [ -t 1 ]; then  # only use alt screen if output is a terminal
       tput smcup  # toggle alt screen on
       /usr/bin/top "$@"
       tput rmcup  # toggle alt screen off
   else
       /usr/bin/top "$@"
   fi
   ```

Comment: With `altscreen on` in my `~/.screenrc` I don't have such an issue.  Have you considered updating the version of `screen` that's installed?  Seems like this is more than one question, also.

Comment: As I said, I have seen the same behavior for years and with several different terminal emulators, and, besides, as an Archlinux user, I am running recent versions of all programs. So it cannot be because of outdated programs, nor because of `screen`’s “inner” configuration specifically.

Comment: So then it seems you have several questions mixed together, and you don't want to consider applying patches from upstream.  Please edit your question to clarify your exact question.  The "better way" in my opinion would be to install current versions of the programs giving you trouble, but it's pretty broad right now.

Comment: Well, I just said that I already have the current versions of all involved programs. I am indeed not interested in patching them myself. I have many reasons not to do that, the first of which being that I don’t know why it is that way, and I guess that there are good reasons for it. Which is precisely why I am asking my first question. I highlighted my question**s** as you requested. I agree that they are pretty vague. I’m not sure what would be a “cleaner” way but, for example, an option I missed, or a standard env var `USE_ALTSCREEN` of which I would have never heard before… would qualify.

Comment: Ah, I misread, I thought you said you DON'T have recent versions of all programs.  My apologies!

Comment: 1. Some people hate the alternate screen feature and not only they don't care to fix programs to work with it, but also go out of their way to break it ;-) 2. patch the corresponding programs. For 2., notice that the switch should also be performed when the program is stopped/continued (eg. with ^Z), not only upon starting/exiting. That's something your wrapper fails to do.

Comment: Instead of 2., you should also consider using alternatives (htop, whiptail, tmux). Notice that simple programs which are using ncurses in the regular way (`initscr()/endwin()`) don't have to do anything special; the ncurses library takes care of everything.

Comment: @mosvy, thanks for your input! I was suspecting that it may be a “political” issue, thanks for confirming it. I will sure look into these alternatives, of which I have already heard as “superior” replacements (more modern, better behaved, better defaults, easier to use…). I think that I will take your comments as my answer, even though this is a negative conclusion.

Comment: On the stop/continue issue, well spotted. Unfortunately, handling SIGSTOP/SIGCONT from a shell script [does not seem easy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451816), if feasible at all. All methods I can think of imply starting the wrapped program in the background, which is not possible since the said program is interactive (for instance, `/usr/bin/top &` fails with the error message “failed tty set: Interrupted system call”). So I guess I will stick with this partial solution. Even though `top_wrapper.sh &` has strange effects…

Comment: Yes, it would be much easier to patch the program rather than to wrap it using a shell script.  I think a better approach would be to write your wrapper in C, so that you can use `waitpid()` to determine when it stops and continues.

Comment: Related: [How to configure screen-restore in a terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85398/5355)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to wrap using a shell script, we can write a short C program, which allows us to switch back to the normal screen when the program is stopped:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* Quick hack; todo: use terminfo instead */
#include <stdlib.h>
static void enter_alt_screen(void)
{
    system("tput smcup");
}
static void leave_alt_screen(void)
{
    system("tput rmcup");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s command args...", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!isatty(fileno(stdout))) {
        /* not a terminal; act normally */
        execvp(argv[1], argv+1);
    }

    enter_alt_screen();
    const pid_t child = fork();
    switch (child) {
    case -1:
        leave_alt_screen();
        perror("fork");
        return 1;
    case 0:
        /* child */
        execvp(argv[1], argv+1);
        leave_alt_screen();
        perror("exec");
        return 1;
    }

    int status;
    while (waitpid(child, &status, WCONTINUED) == child) {
        if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
            leave_alt_screen();
        } else if (WIFCONTINUED(status)) {
            enter_alt_screen();
        } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            leave_alt_screen();
            signal(WTERMSIG(status), signal(SIGTERM, SIG_DFL));
            raise(WTERMSIG(status));
        } else if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            leave_alt_screen();
            return WEXITSTATUS(status);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Great piece of C code. I just don’t get the `WIFSTOPPED` / `WIFCONTINUED` part. If I understand the man page correctly, this should trigger when the child is stopped/continued, yet when I try it with `/bin/top`, pause it with Ctrl+z and resume it with `fg`, this is not detected (the shell prompt shows in the alternate screen). I was only able to trigger it by adding the flag `WUNTRACED` to the function `waitpid()`, and by stopping/continuing the child process with `kill -STOP/-CONT` (but then there is no point, as this does not yield a shell prompt). I don’t really know what I am doing.

Comment: Strange: it works for me with `sleep`, but not with `top` (which is `/usr/bin/top` here).  I don't know why `top` doesn't change back when it's suspended or killed from the shell.